# Why do Facebook messages sometimes fail to send?

Tags: facebook

Sometimes when I send a message on Facebook it says "failed to send message". Why is this? It's happened both on desktop and Android app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually because you have a poor internet connection.

Comment: This user is correct, this is usually the case, at least in my experience it always has been the reason.

Answer (score -1):

Would have to be a really bad connection to do it on his desktop as well. I've been getting it, but for me its because I pasted a URL that Facebook blocks for some reason. Its just a google search for Yvonne Craig on the Images tab. But every single time I try to send it, same error. But I can send anything else ok so its not my connection.

Comment: This is not provide answer.